# How to show a success message to redirected page after submitting from another page using jquery in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I have a reset password form. After submitting it, it redirects to login page. However, it doesn't show any success message upon getting the successful reset password. And, I'm uncertain how can I do this as these are two different **jsp** files. And even if the login page uses the **reset password javascript** code, it still can't be able to show the conditional message. I am using **java spring boot**, **jquery** and **javascript**. This is my code:

**resetPassword.js**

```
    $(".resetPassword").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var password = $("#pass").val();
        var confirmPass = $("#confirmPass").val();

        if(password !== confirmPassword){
            $(".perror").show();
        }
        else {
            alert("Your password changed successfully");
            $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
        }

    });
```

**resetPassword.jsp**

```
<form:form action="/reset_password" method="POST" class="resetPass" modelAttribute="resetPassword">

<div class="alert alert-danger perror" role="alert" style="display: none">Password not match</div>
  <form:input type="hidden" path="token" />
  <div class="form-group-row ">
     <label htmlFor="passwordReset">Password</label>
     <input type="password" id="pass" path="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group-row ">
     <label htmlFor="confirmPasswordReset">Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="confirmPass" placeholder="Confirm Password" required/>
  </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>

</form:form>
```

Now, this is the **login.jsp** in where I want the successful message which currently now I've been showing from alert box however that seems not a good design.

**login.jsp**

```
<form:form action="/login" method="POST" modelAttribute="user" >

<div class="alert alert-success successfulResetPassword" role="alert" style="display: none>Your password changed successfully. Please login using your email and password</div>

<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required/>
 <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="pass" required/>

 </form:form>
```

now all I want, is to show the **div class=successfulResetPassword** after a user reset the password show that the display alter it's value to visible. But I haven't found any good way to this as **reset password** is using a different **js** file and from that submit button I'm redirected the whole scenario to login page. Even if the login page can access that js page still it can't have the value of changing display property :

`$("#successfulResetPassword").show();`. I tried to modify my code like this till now :

**resetPassword.js**

```
else {
      $("#successfulResetPassword").show(); //it could've shown the msg, but can't because it's in button submit condition after redirected to login page which has no **resetPassword** class
      alert("Your password changed successfully");
      $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
  }
```

And this is my backend code:

```
 @PostMapping("/reset_password")
    public String resetPasswordSubmit(Map<String, Object> model, @ModelAttribute("resetPassword") ResetPasswordDTO resetPassword){
        model.put("pageTitle", Constant.PAGE_TITLE);
        GenericResponse response = loginService.changePassword(resetPassword);
        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
            return "redirect:/login";
        }
        model.put("error", "error");
        return "resetPassword";
    }
```

Comment: add a query param with status like `return "redirect:/login?reset=success"`. then in the login page, check if there is a success param and show the pop.

Comment: Also, don't use `alert`, just display the message somewhere on the page